Unity Custom Editor Changing EditorGUI.PropertyField Default Value
I have a custom editor script and it has a PropertyField that allows us to changing names of list elements. My problem in here is, can I assign an initial value to it?
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(InfoList))]
public class InfoListDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        float nameWidth = 100f;

        int indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;

        float nameHeight = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(property.FindPropertyRelative("Name"));

        Rect namePosition = new (position.x, position.y + (position.height - nameHeight) / 2f, nameWidth, nameHeight);
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(namePosition, property.FindPropertyRelative("Name"), GUIContent.none);

        Rect listPosition = new (position.x + nameWidth + 20, position.y, position.width - nameWidth - 20, position.height);
        SerializedProperty listProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative("List");
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(listPosition, listProperty, true);

        EditorGUI.indentLevel = indent;
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }

    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        SerializedProperty listProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative("List");
        float height = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(listProperty, true);
        return height;
    }
}

I tried to achieve that with EditorGUI.LabelField but It messed up my inspector very badly.

I figured it out. I just add this lines and it worked.
if (property.FindPropertyRelative("Name").stringValue == "")
property.FindPropertyRelative("Name").stringValue = "Something";

